# passing collection on marionette.itemview is not working

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am working on a backbone.marionette demo for implementing collection on item view.
But it is not rendering properly. I have created demo in which view is not rendering after I pass collection to it.

```
 var view2 = new MyItemsView({
        collection: options.collection
    });
app.mainRegion.show(view2);
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kslagdive/t9WWC/
How can I do for this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/dfYm2/

Namely:

```
var MyItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#some-template',
    tagName: "li"
});

var MyItemsView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: MyItemView,
    tagName: "ul"
});
```

and then

```
    var view2 = new MyItemsView({
        collection: options.collection
    });
    app.mainRegion.show(view2);
```

Let Marionette iterate over the collection an render the views for you. That's it's role. Otherwise, there's little incentive to use Marionette instead of plain Backbone.

There's also a more comprehensive step-by-step introduction to displaying a collection with Marionette in this free pdf: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use CompositeView or CollectionView instead.

```
var template = _.template($('#some-template').html());
var MyItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: template
});

var MyItemsView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemView: MyItemView
});
```

And template:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/html">
    <%- title %>
</script>
```

Comment: yes thanks. it works.
can we iterate over model items into template to show them all using iterator function..?

Comment: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-appendhtml